# Python -- reference variables that don't exist

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, default-value, instance-variables

I was learning the tkinter package in Python and I didn't understand next code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

As I understand `self` refers to the class and when the code says `self.hi_there` I expect a global variable in that class that has to be declared previously. How is `hi_there` created?

Also what is the use of having "master=None" in the `__init__` method? Wouldn't it be the same if I skip `=None` part since I do `app = Application(master=root)`?

Comment: Not sure why you think they don't exist.

Comment: It’s created at `self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)`.

Comment: And it's created as a global variable ? what's the meaning of self here? why not simply put "hi_there = tk.Button(self)"

Comment: These questions can be answered by working through a basic python tutorial. None of what you ask is specifically related to tkinter.

Comment: No. `self` is **not like a global variable at all**. It is the *instance namespace*, *not the local or global* ones. You should read through some tutorials on OOP in python. Also, Python does not have variable declarations.

Answer (score 1):

`self` refers to the instance. `self.hi_there` is an instance variable. By doing `app = Application(master=root)` you create an instance of `Application` and save it to `app`. In your case `self` is `app`.

You don't need to declare properties before you create them (though it's considered to be a good practice to create them in `__init__`).

Consider example:

```
class A()
    pass

a = A()
a.prop = 2
print(a.prop) #=> 2
```

About `master=None` -- indeed, you can use just `master` if it's your code and you know you will pass it.

Comment: but in that example it doesn't change anything if i simply create the widgets like `hi_there = tk.Button(self)` instead of `self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)`
Whats the meaning of self here?

Comment: I dont know how to explain, i tried the code without the self at the begining at each widget and it doesn't change anything (that i notice). Why not simply put "hi_there = tk.Button(self)"?

Answer (score 1):

`self` refers to the instance of the class and therefor `self.hi_there = foo` will create a new instance variable and assign it to `foo` like:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'bar'

a = Test()
print(a.foo)

# output:
# bar
```

---

And `master=None` is setting a default `None` value to `master` unless you supply that value, for example:

```
app = Application() # here master will be None
app = Application(master=root) # here master will be root
```

This can be used with any function, here is another example:

```
def plus(num=0):
    return num+num

print(plus(1))
print(plus())

# output:
# 2
# 0
```